# How do I synch the Arduino PID library with an external timer for turn-rate control?

Tags: timers, isr, pid

I have been trying to use the Arduino PID library for controlling the rate of turn (in deg/sec) of a wall-following robot.

The robot's operating system uses TIMER5 on an Arduino MEGA2560 to update a number of time-sensitive parameters (heading, front/back/left/right distances, etc) which are used throughout the code. For turn rate control, the difference between the current and previous headings (appropriately modified for 0/180 transitions) is multiplied by 10 to get deg/sec, and then this value is the 'input' to a PID. The PID output is a speed control to the wheels to achieve the desired turn rate setpoint.

Unfortunately, the current Arduino PID library has an internal timer (that can be changed, but not disabled) which has it's own idea of time.  In addition, the PID library's internal timer isn't available to the outside world - it is only used in PID::Compute().

The typical code configuration for using a PID is something like the following:

```
loop()
{
    //lots of other stuff
    if(TIMER5 ISR has been triggered)
    {
        //compute turn rate = 10*delta_heading
    }

    if(myPID.Compute()) //the internal timer is used inside this function
    {
       //use the PID output to control something (like wheel speeds)
    }
}
```

loop() runs at max speed, but myPID.Compute() only generates a new output when the internal PID timer elapses (otherwise it returns immediately without doing anything).  However, the turn rate input is being computed on a different schedule, leading to unpredictable behavior.

A possible solution is:

```
loop()
{
    //lots of other stuff

    if(myPID.Compute()) //the internal timer is used inside this function
    {
        New_Hdg_Val = GetNewHdgVal();
        turn_rate = ComputeTurnRate(New_Hdg_Val, Prev_Hdg_Val);
        Prev_Hdg_Val = New_Hdg_Val;
        
       //use the PID output to control something (like wheel speeds)
    }
}
```

So now the turn rate is computed on the same time intervals as PID::Compute(), which looks OK, as long as the timer value being used by the PID is the same as the TIMER5 ISR value being used by the rest of the program; clunky, inelegant, but maybe OK.

Unfortunately, because the PID computes a new output value inside PID::Compute(), the new value computation comes BEFORE the turn rate computation, which means the turn rate being used to produce the new output uses turn rate information that is AT LEAST 100mSec out of date (assuming the default 100mSec PID sample time setting) - ouch!!

So, how do others use the Arduino PID library in systems with an external (to the PID library) timing source?

Comment: I don't know how others use the PID Lib ;-). Without having thougt much about the problem: How about computing the turn rate in each loop cycle? Outside of the  the `if(myPID.Compute())` block. Does it cause a problem, if it is computed before every `myPID.Compute` call? You waste a small amount of computing time, but you got the most actual values for the turn rate.

Comment: Peter, I certainly could do that. The computation is trivial, but getting the heading measurement from the MPU6050 is not, and there isn't any guarantee that a (blocking) MPU6050 measurement won't start just before the PID's internal timer would have elapsed, meaning that now the PID::Compute() cycles aren't periodic anymore.  This is a big problem because the internal PID math assumes periodicity.

Comment: I don't think reading the MPU is a problem. Even if you read all values from it (I don't know if that's the case) you can reach a sampling rate of 100 HZ. That means max. 10 ms per read out. And if you need the value for the `compute()` you have to read the MPU before the PID executes, so it blocks the PID in any way.  The Compute Method of the PID works with `millis()` and a sample interval of 100 msec by default. If that starts max. 10  msec later, who cares? And, you do "lots of other stuff" in the loop function before it. How much time does that need?  ;-)

Comment: I looked into the code of the compute method, and honestly I  am not very impressed of it. The author needs constant time intervals, because he uses a trick to save a division and a multiplication (derivative, integral). But now every delay in the loop can result in errors in the integral and derivative.  He claims that industrial controller run best within constant intervals.  But an industrial controller runs  on a real time systems that garantees fix intervals. And the Arduino `loop`  provides no real time feature. Especially, if there is a lot of other stuff performed.

Comment: If I would need a PID controller, I would write my own version. The author links to a piece of code I would prefer to use.  http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2011/04/improving-the-beginners-pid-introduction/  (but without the "time interval"  improvements)

Comment: You sync it by calling the `myPID.Compute()` function in your external timer handler function.  If your loop function is lengthy, move your time-critical functions to a timer handler.

Comment: I use TIMER5 on the Mega 2560 to run everything that is time-sensitive, including PID calculations.  I use a custom PID_calcs function that mimics the internal workings of PID.Compute(), and PID_calcs is called each time TIMER5 is fired, guaranteeing equal time intervals.